# wpf OpenFileDialog with many filename patterns

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I have a simple mechanism that opens files in WPF using OpenFileDialog. So I am opening sqlite files and I made Filter and it works, but i wanted to narrow selection even more by giving file pattern names in FileName property, so my code looks like:

```
    public string[] OpenFiles()
    {
        var fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            Filter = "SQLite files (*.db, *.sqlite, *.7z)|*.db;*.sqlite;*.7z",
            FileName = "*events*|*currents*",
            FilterIndex = 1,
            Multiselect = true
        };

        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() != true) return new List<string>();

        string[] files = fileDialog.FileNames;
        return files;
    }
```

So What I am trying to do to is add multi patterns to FileName to accept only files with events or currents in it.
Basing on Filter property I tried to make similar operation result was not what I was expecting.
If I add just *events* then it will work (well work as it filters files with events work in it)

So is there a way to filter multiple file names?

Comment: All patterns should be part of the `filter`. Try `"SQLite files (*.db, *.sqlite, *.7z)|*events*.db;*events*.sqlite;*events*.7z;*currents*.db;*currents*.sqlite;*currents*.7z"`.

Comment: It works.Add it as answer so I can mark it